# Installing .BAR file in BlackBerry 10

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, cascade

I have only .bar file and its respective debug token . I don't have any code of the project. It was run on other device and created .bar file. Now I want to run it on my BB10 device with this BAR file. I came to know that it can be done by using DDPB tool .

```
How can I do this.?
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag the .bar file into your qnx editor work-space
2. Now click install button by selecting target device
3. It will run on simulator without any prompt
4. Try it to install by selecting mobile as target device